# Prove that 4 more or less than square of an odd prime is related to another prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume a function $f(t)=2t+1$. If $f(t)=c^2\pm4$ where $c$ is an odd prime number. How can I prove that $t$ has only $4$ unique factors i.e. $t=2k$ where $k$ is any prime.

It works always for $c\gt3$, for example: $$c=5 \implies f(t) =21~or~29 \implies t=10~or~ 14 \\
 c=7 \implies f(t) =45~or~53 \implies t=22~or~26 \\ c=11 \implies f(t) =117~or~125 \implies t=58~or~62$$.

Comment: You must have a typo.  $f(10/14)=2(10/14)+1=10/7+1=17/7$, not $21/29$; also what you wrote has $f(t)=(c^2-4)/(c^2+4)$, not $f(t)=c^2\pm4$

Comment: I think that OP is (confusingly) using $/$ as a sort of respective OR operation, not division.

Comment: Oh I meant 10 or 14 accounting for the $\pm$ sign not actually 10 divided by 7!  Maybe better to write as OR?

Comment: Yes, in mathematics, / usually means divided by

Comment: Did you try $c=37$ ?

Comment: $c=29$ with negative sign leads to $t=418=2\cdot 11\cdot 19$.. $c=19$ with positive sign leads to $t=182=2\cdot 7\cdot 13$. I am afraid you fell for the big law of small numbers. (As J.W.Tanner implies, $c=37$ fails for both signs)

Comment: $c=19$ gives $365$ so $t = 182 = 2\cdot 91$

Comment: I need to amend that it should be a product of primes.. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean---all positive integers are products of primes. Since you've already received answers addressing the original form of the question, it would be appropriate to formulate your question as a new question instead.

Comment: This may be useful for you to check if possible. https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/prime-numbers-to-10k.html

Comment: Another question:  instead of the false claim $k$ is prime, did you mean that $k$ is not divisible by $2, 3,$ or $5$?

Comment: I admit that my question was wrong. Sorry to all! I apologize. But if you can prove that it is not divisible by $2,3,5$, it would be nice too!

Comment: I took the liberty of posting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214548/prove-c2-1-4-pm-1-is-not-divisible-by-2-3-or-5-if-c3-is-an-odd-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: $c = 149$, and so $c^2+4 = 22205$, $4k = 2t = 22204$, $k = 5551$ is not a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally true, as given by examples in the comments.

E.g., $c=37\implies f(t)=1365$ or $ 1373 \implies t=682=2\times11\times31$ or $t=686=2\times7\times7
\times7$.