# Prove $(c^2-1)/4 \pm 1$ is not divisible by $2, 3, $ or $5$ if $c>3$ is an odd prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212269/prove-that-4-more-or-less-than-square-of-an-odd-prime-is-related-to-another-prim) asked the other day, [RTn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/646617/rtn) conjectured that, if $c>3$ is an odd prime,

then $k=\dfrac{c^2\pm4-1}4=\dfrac{c^2-1}4\pm1$ is prime.  As the [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212269/prove-that-4-more-or-less-than-square-of-an-odd-prime-is-related-to-another-prim/3212294#3212294) and comments there show,

this conjecture is not true; some numbers of that form are multiples of $7$, $11$, $13$, etc.

I suspect, however, that [RTn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/646617/rtn) was misled because $k$ cannot be divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$.

This question is how to prove this.

I'm taking the option of answering my own question, but I'd appreciate feedback or other answers.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: My guess: some users seem not to like self-answered questions and/or hold them to much higher standards. But it's only a guess...

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to characterize *all* prime divisors $p > 5$.

$\!\!\bmod p\!:\,\ 0\equiv (x^2-1)/4\pm 1\iff x^2\equiv \mp4+1 \equiv \color{#c00}{-3},\color{#0a0}5$

By quadratic reciprocity $\,(\color{#c00}{-3}|p) = 1\!\iff\! p\equiv1\pmod{\!3};\,$ $\,(\color{#0a0}5|p)=1\!\iff\! p\equiv\pm1 \pmod{\!5}$

It follows by CRT that the prime divisors $p>5$ are exactly those primes $\not\equiv 2,8\pmod{\!15},\,$ i.e. those primes $\equiv 1,4,7,11,13,14\pmod{\!15}$. Hence - further - it is never divisible by these primes 
$\, 17,23,47,53,83,107,113,137,167,173,197,\ldots$

Comment: Very nice; thank you; +1

Answer (score 2):

If $c>3$ is an odd prime, then $c$ is not divisible by $2, 3, $ or $5,$

unless $c=5, $ in which case the claim can be easily verified.

If $c$ is not divisible by $2,$ then $c^2-1=(c+1)(c-1)$ is the product of two consecutive

even numbers so divisible by $8,$ so $\dfrac {c^2-1}4$ is even, so $\dfrac{c^2-1}4\pm1$ is not divisible by $2$.
 If $c$ is not divisible by $3$, then $c+1$ or $c-1$ is, so $c^2-1$ is, so $\dfrac{c^2-1}4$ is (since $4\equiv1\mod3),$

so $\dfrac{c^2-1}4\pm1$ is not.

Finally, if $c$ is not divisible by $5,$ 
 then $c^2\equiv 1$ or $4\mod5$, so $c^2-1\equiv 0$ or $3\mod 5$;

since $4\equiv-1\mod 5,$ that means $\dfrac{c^2-1 }4\equiv0 $ or $2\mod 5$, so $\dfrac{c^2-1}4\pm1\not\equiv0\mod5.$